# matplotlib does'nt plot the data on basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot a simple temperature plot from GFS data using pygrib. I used the examples from the following links:-

http://jswhit.github.io/pygrib/docs/index.html
http://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/waves/examples/usingpython.shtml

Here is the sample code I am trying to do:-

```
import pygrib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

grib = 'data/gfs.t00z.pgrb2f00'
grbs = pygrib.open(grib)

grbs.seek(0)
grb = grbs.select(name='Temperature')[0]
data, lats, lons = grb.data(lat1=0,lat2=35,lon1=60,lon2=100)
print data  # <<--- This has some values but not plotted in the map.
m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=0, urcrnrlat=35,\
                llcrnrlon=60, urcrnrlon=100, resolution='c')

x, y = m(lats, lons)
m.drawcoastlines()
cs = m.pcolor(x, y, np.squeeze(data))
m.colorbar(cs, location='bottom', pad="10%")
plt.title('Simple temperature plot from GRiB')
plt.show()
```

The terminal output shows the availability of data on 'data' variable:-

```
python2.7 grib_plot.py 
[[ 225.8  225.8  225.8 ...,  225.9  225.8  225.7]
 [ 225.7  225.7  225.6 ...,  225.8  225.8  225.7]
 [ 225.6  225.6  225.5 ...,  225.8  225.8  225.8]
 ..., 
 [ 229.1  229.1  229.1 ...,  231.1  230.8  230.6]
 [ 228.3  228.5  228.8 ...,  231.3  230.7  230.5]
 [ 227.4  227.8  228.3 ...,  231.6  231.1  230.8]]
```

However, the resulting image does not show the plotting of temperature

[image: sample grib data temp plot]

Any help to solve the issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my bad that I used wrong coding. It is supposed to be

`x, y = m(lons, lats)`

It works now.